# Is it necessary to pass a type parameter to static functions in a generic class?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

**My class:** my class takes one type parameter, and has one static method which does not use the type parameter:

```
class GenericClass<T> {

    static func blub(x: Int) -> Int {
        return x + 1
    }
}
```

**My problem:** when I attempt to use the static function, my code does not compile:

```
let z: Int = GenericClass.blub(4) // doesn't compile
```

I've come up with two workarounds:

1. give `GenericClass` a type argument -- doesn't matter which type:

   ```
   let y: Int = GenericClass<Void>.blub(4)
   ```
2. create a second class, which doesn't have any type parameters, to hold the static methods

So I know how to get the code working, although it may not be the optimal solution.  But my question is about why Swift works this way.

**My question:**

Why doesn't `let y: Int = GenericClass.blub(4)` compile?

It should compile because `blub` is a static method and therefore shouldn't have any interaction with the type parameters, which are only used for **instances**, not for static methods and variables.  Or at least, that's what I expected.

Where am I wrong?  How do class-level type parameters and static methods interact in Swift?

Is there a better way to solve this problem than the two workarounds I tried?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Your question should be "Why doesn't `let z: Int = GenericClass.blub(4)` compile, no?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700989/how-to-add-type-methods-to-generic-types-in-swift

Comment: Nice, thanks for pointing that out @BJHStudios :thumbsup:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GenericClass` is not a concrete type in Swift. There's no way to talk about it any more than you can talk about the type `Array` without providing its type parameter. (The specific feature Swift lacks that would allow this is called "higher-kinded types.")

Static methods are tied to the concrete type (`GenericClass<T>`) not to the higher-kinded type (`GenericClass`). In order to access the static methods, it needs to know the actual type you want.

While it's true you're not currently using the type parameter in this class method, there is nothing stopping you (or a subclass!) from doing so. Since you have no way to promise that `T` will never occur in this method, there's no way for Swift to allow you to ignore it.

Answer (score 10):

The other answers are correct in their explanations, but you can in fact get the behavior you intuitively expected with this:

```
extension GenericClass where T == Any {

    static func blub(x: Int) -> Int {
        return x + 1
    }
}
```

Now this compiles:

```
let z: Int = GenericClass.blub(x: 4)
```

Note: `Any` is sometimes seen as a code smell. That said, it is the right tool here. The `where T == Any` guard here can be interpreted as "for this static function, I don't care what T is, it can be anything", which is what we want.

Comment: This is a clever solution, but the explanation is not quite correct. The `where T ==` clause could be anything. `Any` is not special here. This clause doesn't mean "I don't care what T is." I means "when calling `blub`, T is exactly Any." That's different than T being something that conforms to Any. It's the Any existential type. I'd slightly recommend using either `where T == Void` or `where T == Never` here instead of `Any` (but it's not a big deal either way). There's also a very subtle restriction on using this: https://gist.github.com/rnapier/348b50a1cc2007d22ef350a5b7f844bc

Comment: (But I think this is a very clever solution, and may even be a very good way to do it for most problems.)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info. If I may ask, what are the reasons why `where T == Void` or `where T == Never` would be better?

Comment: `Any` is somewhat bad because it confuses the reader, who will likely interpret it the way you did (that it means "any type" rather than "an Any existential"). `Never` IMO is the correct type, and really captures that this applies to no values at all (which is what `Never` means). It's like "static" in that sense. But I'd worry that readers might again misunderstand it and think it means it never applies and can't be called. The middle ground between those two is `Void`, which think casual users will understand, while being close to correct. (But this has no real impact on the final result.)

Answer (score 5):

You can, in fact, reference generic type parameters from static methods. For example:

```
struct Wrapper<T> {
    var value: T

    private init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    static func wrap(_ value: T) -> Self {
        return Self(value)
    }
}
```

In this case the generic parameter can be inferred:

```
let wrapped = Wrapper.wrap(3) // => Wrapper<Int>
```

Comment: His `T` parameter is not related to `Int` in his question. You can't infer it